# If condition isn't met?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, character

I want to read a `String` character by character which is already in an array.

```
String ss = "makassar";
String my_array[] = ss.split("");
for (int i = 1; i < ss.length()+1; i++) {
  if (my_array[i]=="m") {
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Array is M", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
     toast.show();
     // Toast not show
  }
}
```

Toast is not getting displayed. Why? Any idea?

Comment: As an aside, you may want to rethink your curly brace strategy.

Comment: @summea I've seem lots of different ways to do braces, but nothing as unreadable as that.

Comment: @summea - just because he happens to like Horstmann style doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - it's a known style, just not widely used in my experience.

Comment: @BrianRoach Didn't say it was wrong.  Just suggesting something (potentially,) more readable, like this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/should-curly-braces-appear-on-their-own-line

Comment: ::shrug:: and I personally don't care for braces on the same line. It's a personal preference thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and not `operator==` to compare strings.

`operator==` checks for **identity** of objects [if the left and the right are the same object], while `equals()` checks **equality** [if the 2 strings equal each other].

Change this:

```
if (my_array[i]=="m")
```

to this:

```
if ("m".equals(my_array[i]))
```

Also, note that `my_array[1]` is the second element, and not the first, so you might want to start from `i = 0` and not `i = 1`

Comment: Wow.. Thanks very much man.. oh ya, array start index = 0;
Sorry, coz I'm newbie..

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop to loop `i` from `0` to less than `ss.length()`.